# How do I activate Windows 7 VMs run as a server cluster?

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-machine, license-key

I have a C# program that only runs on Windows 7 (various reasons) and only one instance of it can run on the OS at a time (similar reasons). I am looking to parallelize the program by launching several instances in separate virtual machines. How do I do this while properly activating each instances?

The licensing documentation I found talks a lot about per-user usage, and per-device usage, and remote login usage. For my case, I will never even be logging into the VMs; everything runs as a service on startup (pre-login). Only one user will ever be using it (me).

I thought I would be able to use an Enterprise or purchase Professional or Home licenses to do it (I have enough valid instances of all three for the number of VMs I want to run), but then I read the articles on MS and became more confused:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/d/98d6a56c-4d79-40f4-8462-da3ecba2dc2c/licensing_windows_desktop_os_for_virtual_machines.pdf

http://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/feature/Demystifying-Microsoft-virtual-desktop-licensing-SA-vs-VDA-vs-CDL

Comment: Is that for personal use or commercial use?

Comment: @Alexrgs commercial. but im certainly curious how personal is different

Comment: the difference is for personal use(Learning propose) you can use a MS dreamspark licence (now MS imagine) or MSDN.

Comment: which msdn license?

Comment: From a MSDN subscription.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/subscriptions/aa336858.aspx

Comment: Sure. I count 17 different windows 7 licenses in there. Not clear which one says I can install on a set of VMs. My interpretation of the links in the original question says none of them are applicable.